# How to fade color and set margin-left for the title's box with CSS

Tags: html, css

What I've done here is just make a box like the image below but how to fade a color and set
 `margin-left= 10px; margin-top: 5px` for the title's box with CSS

[image: Pic]

---

**<kbd>[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LRdvm/)</kbd>**

**HTML:**

```
<div id="_div">
    <span class="_top">Company Performance</span>
    <span class="_content">Electric Consumption: 2300kW</span>
<div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#_div {
    display: block;
    -webkit-border-radius: 7px;
    -moz-border-radius: 7px;
    border-radius: 7px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #e0e6e8;
    border: 1px solid #c1dee0;
}
._top {
    display: block;
    background-color: #D0E3EC;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 7px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 7px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 7px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 7px;
    border-top-left-radius: 7px;
    border-top-right-radius: 7px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #c1dee0;
}
._content {
    display: block;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```

Comment: How far right are you trying to go? Where exactly are you trying to go and do with this?

Comment: I am heading to highlight how to solve my first problem with `._top { linear-gradient( #D0E3EC, #e9f2f6 ); }` - This is for fading color.

Answer (score 1):

Not clear why you want to use the margin
if you want to align the text use padding with _top class

Remove all the padding from _top class and add

```
padding: 5px 0 5px 10px;
```

To fade the color use **`opacity: .5`**

Answer (score 0):

To solve my problems, I have used `linear-gradient(#D0E3EC, #e9f2f6);` and `padding-left: 10px; padding-top: 5px;`. To be more detail, please have a look on the code below.

**Code:**

```
._top {
    display: block;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 7px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 7px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 7px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 7px;
    border-top-left-radius: 7px;
    border-top-right-radius: 7px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #c1dee0;
    background-image:
    linear-gradient(#D0E3EC, #e9f2f6);
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-top: 5px;
}
```

## [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/LRdvm/1/)